# Extract youtube meta-info with regex

Tags: python, regex, youtube

I want to extract youtube video meta-info by using python regular expression, here is what i have found to extract video url and video title

```
import re
import urllib2

#https://www.youtube.com/user/<channel_name>/videos
#Here the channel name is schooloflifechannel
site = "https://www.youtube.com/user/schooloflifechannel/videos"
videos = [] 
#re_filter defines a filter to find all the anchor tags using regular expressions
m_filter = r'<ul.*?/ul>'
read_url = urllib2.urlopen(site)
re_filter = r'<a.*?/a>'
all_links_temp = re.findall(re_filter,read_url.read(),re.MULTILINE)
#This varialbe denotes class of each video link of the channel
video_link_class = 'class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link'
video_titles = []
video_links = []
#This loop finds all the titles and links for videos and stores them in two seperate lists. 
#You could also use a dictionary here which might make things easier for parsing further
for temp in all_links_temp:
    if video_link_class in temp:
        title_filter = r'title=".*?"'
        video_title_temp = re.findall(title_filter,temp,re.MULTILINE)
        video_titles.append(video_title_temp)
    url_filter = r'href=".*?"'
    video_link_temp = re.findall(url_filter,temp,re.MULTILINE)
    video_links.append(video_link_temp)
#This simple prints the Title followed by the link of each video in the lists
j = 0       
for i in video_titles:
    temp_title = str(i)
    temp_title = temp_title[9:-3]
    temp_link = str(video_links[j])
    temp_link = "https://www.youtube.com"+temp_link[8:-3]
    videos.append((temp_link, temp_title))
    j = j + 1
print videos
```

Now i also wanted to extract meta-info from **class="yt-lockup-meta-info"** and join all of the results together in this format ("VIDEO_URL", "VIDEO_TITLE", "VIDEO_UPLOAD_DATE"). How can i do it with python **re**

Comment: it much more simplier to use lxml (http://lxml.de/) instead re.

You can use css selectors with it

Comment: Thank you so much pecos but my project is based on mobile(android) and if i include lxml or beautfullsoup in my project the final apk will be so big 17mb with lxml and 11mb without lxml

Comment: Why don't you simply use the YouTube API? It gives you all this information but in an easier to parse JSON string plus whenever YouTube changes e.g. the class names of video links your script will not work anymore. With the API you're safe of any changes they make to their HTML page